# The regularity of a piecewise constant function in Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, piecewise-continuity

I want to know what the "highest" regularity is for a piecewise constant function. For example:
$$ f(x)=\left\{\begin{align*} &1, & x\in [0,1),\\ &0, & x\in (-1,0).\end{align*}\right. $$
We know that **$f\in L^p(\Omega)$** where $\Omega=(-1,1)$ and $p\geq 1$, but **$f\not\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$** ($W^{k,p}$ denotes the Sobolev space whose functions and their $k$-th derivatives are both in $L^p$ space) since $f(0^+)\not=f(0^-)$.

Now, I am wondering may the function $f(x)$ has any higher regularities? such as **$f\in W^{\varepsilon,p}(\Omega)$** with $0 < \varepsilon < \frac12$ (or $0<\varepsilon <1$)? If this is right, how to prove it?

Comment: At least for $p=2$, (where you can use Fourier series to easily define and interpret the fractional Sobolev norms) you can show that $f\in W^{s,2}$, for any $0<s<1/2$ and $f\notin W^{1/2,2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. You remind me the definition of the fractional Sobolev spaces by Fourier series. It's actually easy to show that $f\in W^{s,2}$ for $0<s<1/2$. However, it's not easy to see this if we use the definition $\int_\Omega\int_\Omega \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{n+sp}} dxdy<+\infty$ for $0<s<1$.

Comment: My guess, based only on a hunch, is that the threshold for general $p$ is something like $0<s<1/p$ (which is consistent with it utterly failing in the $L^\infty$ case (it's not Hölder of any order), while the $L^1$ case barely fails in the $s=1$ case (the function is in $BV$, an enlargement of $W^{1,1}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that dealing with your definition of fractional Sobolev spaces in not too bad.

We show: Let $1\leq p\leq\infty$ and $0<s<1$, then $f\in W^{s,p}(-1,1)$ if and only if $0<s<1/p$.

We only treat the case $p<\infty$, the other is simply noting that $f$ is not Hölder  continuous of any order.

First notice that $|f(x)-f(y)|=1$ whenever $x\in (0,1)$ and $y\in (-1,0)$ or vice versa, and $|f(x)-f(y)|=0$ otherwise. So that means, by symmetry,
$$
\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 \dfrac{|f(x)-f(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{1+sp}}\, dx dy = 2 \int_{-1}^0\int_0^1\dfrac{dxdy}{|x-y|^{1+sp}} = 2\int_0^1\int_0^1 \dfrac{dxdy}{(x+y)^{1+sp}}.
$$

Now do a change of variables $z=x+y$ in the inner integral to write
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1\dfrac{dxdy}{(x+y)^{1+sp}}= \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{sp}\left( y^{-sp}- (y+1)^{-sp}\right)\, dy.
$$

The second term has no singularity for any $s, p$, while the first one is integrable if and only if $sp<1$, which gives the result.

Comment: Wonderful answer! Thank you so much! By the way, $s=0$ is OK since $f\in L^p$.